# How to Access Pointer Values in Parse Database

Tags: ios, sql, swift, parse-platform

I am working on an iOS app, running on Parse(backend).

I am having problems with accessing the contents of another class from a query I made.

So I have this table. Let's call it "Contests". it has the following data:
name,
date start,
date end,
pointer to organization table (the objectid)

And then the organization table:
name,
number of Facebook likes,

I want to be able to access the name of the organization and every other detail a certain contest has. Will I have to put a query inside another query, slight problem with that is that the queries require waiting time and it accomplishes it in the background. So I have:

```
findInBackground() {
   findInBackground() {
   }
}
```

Is there any better way to do this? Also I am getting multiple objects at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a query on your Contest table with whatever requirements you have but then add an includeKey call:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Contests")

//...Other query requirements

query.includeKey("organization")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
}
```

includeKey will force fetch of the organization along with the contest details in 1 query.

Comment: Hi! The "organization" is the table name right? How do I access the name attribute?